# Inno Setup AppUserModelID & file associations for sub applications

Tags: windows, inno-setup, file-type

After days of searching and MSDN reading, I am hoping to get some help with this issue.
In Inno Setup, we are registering the main application in the [Icons] section with AppUserModelID: "OurProduct.Name"
This is fine and desirable behavior.

Next we are registering file types for a sub application of our program.
The file associations are all getting registered correctly.

The strange behavior comes in the combination of the AppUserModelID being set with the File Association setting the open file flag for the association.
ValueData: "{app}.{MySubAppExe} ""%1"""

When a registered file is opened it opens the app as expected but the ICON in the taskbar becomes the icon for the main registered application instead of the icon for the program and is grouped with the main application.  If the program is launched without a file, the icon is normal and no grouping occurs (desired behavior).

If the "%1" is removed from the fiel type registration the files open the sub application as desired with the correct icon and no grouping. The problem is the file is not opened with the app.

Removing the AppUserModelID registration causes issues in the Taskbar if a user decides to Pin the application, but when a file of the registered type is opened the sub application is opened with the file as desired and no grouping occurs. The problem being with the pinning of the main app to the Taskbar.

How do I get the main app registered so the Taskbar issues are resolved and register a file type association for a sub application without grouping with the main application and without altering the sub application icon, when a file of the registered type is opened?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is about [tag:inno-setup]. It's rather about the correct Windows registry settings. Using a different tags might bring you an attention from a more appropriate community.

Comment: What additional tag/s would you suggest? I already have "windows" and "file-type" in addition to "inno-setup". Thanks for your suggestion.